# MudBlazor - How can I hide the validation error message?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

With the following model:

```cs
public class LoginVM
{
    // ...
    [Required]
    public string? Password { get; set; }
}
```

and the following HTML:

```html
<EditForm Model="@model" OnValidSubmit="@Submit">
    ...
    <MudTextField T="string?" For="@(() => model.Password)" @bind-Value="model.Password"
                  Label="Password" Variant="Variant.Outlined" InputType="@PasswordInput"
                  Adornment="Adornment.End" AdornmentIcon="@PasswordInputIcon"
                  OnAdornmentClick="TogglePasswordBox" />
    ...
</EditForm>
```

I get the following UI:

[image]

How can I hide the error message and just keep the visual red border and label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be enough:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = " ")]
public string? Password { get; set; }
```

Important: " ", not just "".

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the UI element for error message will still be rendered and the Login button will move down a little. I wanted the HTML elements not to be moved.